# Play SHOUTcast DNAS without entering admin panel

Tags: user-agent, shoutcast

I need URL of a SHOUTcast streaming to be played in browser **without** entering administration panel and **without** adding **"/;"** Nor **"/stream"** at the end of the URL.

I give you the example of 2 SHOUTcast streaming URLs where one does what I want and the other does not.

If you open this streaming [A](https://stm6-ssl.painelcast.com:6934) in Mozilla Firefox you will see that a player appears and plays the sound. Now if you open this streaming [B](https://audiossl.radiosolution.info:9625) in the same browser you will see that it goes to the Shoutcast administration panel.

(*I advise you to watch it in Mozilla because if they do it in Chrome or any Chromium based browser, the player will not be seen because these last browsers download streaming instead of showing the player*.)

To achieve the same thing as streaming A, it would be enough to add a slash and a semicolon at the end of streaming B or "/stream" and this would [result](https://audiossl.radiosolution.info:9625/;).

But that solution does not work for a project I'm testing, **I need the streaming URL to end in the port with nothing later**, just like streaming A.

I've been searching the internet for information for over a week and haven't found anything on how to accomplish this.
Someone help me please.
Best regards
Juan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem in another way.
I have created independent variables for sound URLs and metadata.
To get metadata I have used `https://host:port`
And for the sound `https://host:port/stream`
This way I avoid that the browser recognizes my streaming as html and it plays without problems and I get the metadata correctly . :)